# Using servlet filters with IBM Connections

Tags: java, servlet-filters, ibm-connections

Hi I have the following problem:

I am "customizing" IBM Connections 4.0, I need to do a terms and agreement popup and obviously have to validate whether certain user has already accepted such terms or not. I am using  servlet filters to "intercept" the url pattern /homepage/*, for such purpose I created a web application that I installed in the WAS 7 server on which the IBM Connections is host. My question, and problem, is: does it matter if I install my web application in a different node from that of the IBM Connections installation?

Comment: well, in the case the user has already accepted the termns and agreement the pop up won´t appear (the login form will just follow its normal flow, directing to j_security_check and finally to the homepage), in the case the user had not already accepted terms and agreement, well the pop up will show up, ask the user wheter to accept or not, and finally take the user to the homepage (again, j_security_check will be activated first, as normal). My real problem is that, being a new to WAS technology, I am not sure if I need to install my application in the same node IBM Connections is installed.

Comment: if the user accepted terms the filter will intercept the j_security_check call and register the user in a database (one of my own, Sorry if I did not mention that). and That is the tricky part, I am not sure if the filter will intercept requests from /home/* if the application is not installed in the same node as I said before.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd use a filter... why don't you just edit the login page, and secure all pages... http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM+Connections+4.0+documentation#action=openDocument&res_title=Customizing_the_login_page_ic40&content=pdcontent&sa=true

Comment: Well, the only way I knew to edit my jsp and do what I needed to do was using scriplets, but, as you might know, using scriplets is not a recommended way to do things. In the end, however, I had to use scriplets since using filters was not the way to do things either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who could be interested: It doest matter as filters intercept or "act" in the context of the web application on which they were declared and mapped to.